# How to implement randomized O(n) algorithm for finding median of unsorted array in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, median

I have this code for finding median of an unsorted array in O(n) expected time, O(n^2) worst case. I use longs because I want to be able to hold long values.

```
public class Randomized {

    long kthSmallestHelper(long arr[], long l, long r, long k) 
    { 
        if (k > 0 && k <= r - l + 1) 
        { 
            long pos = randomPartition(arr, l, r); 

            if (pos-l == k-1) 
                return arr[(int)pos]; 

            if (pos - l > k - 1) 
                return kthSmallestHelper(arr, l, pos - 1, k);

            return kthSmallestHelper(arr, pos + 1, r, k - pos + l - 1); 
        } 
          return Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
    } 

    void swap(long arr[], long i, long j) 
    { 
        long temp = arr[(int)i]; 
        arr[(int)i] = arr[(int)j]; 
        arr[(int)j] = temp; 
    } 

    long partition(long arr[], long l, long r) 
    { 
        long x = arr[(int)r], i = l; 
        for (long j = l; j <= r - 1; j++) 
        { 
            if (arr[(int)j] <= x) 
            { 
                swap(arr, i, j); 
                i++; 
            } 
        } 
        swap(arr, i, r); 
        return i; 
    } 

    long randomPartition(long arr[], long l, long r) 
    { 
        long n = r - l + 1; 
        long pivot = (long)(Math.random()) * (n - 1); 
        swap(arr, pivot + 1, r); 
        return partition(arr, l, r); 
    } 

    long kthSmallestRandom(long arr[], long k){
        return kthSmallestHelper(arr, 0, arr.length - 1, k);

    }

}
```

But when I run it

```
    long[] array =  {12, 3, 5, 7, 4, 19, 26}; //median is 7
    Randomized rand = new Randomized();
    System.out.println(rand.kthSmallestRandom(array, (array.length + 1)/2));
```

It's incorrect (it returns 4).

My idea was to use this version of the kth smallest number to say that I want the (length/2)th smallest, which is the median.

What is wrong with my idea or implementation?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just sort the array and then pick the middle element? You can sort arrays with a built-in method in O(n*log(n))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but just changing all longs to ints fixed it. It now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small error in your `kthSmallestHelper` function in this line:

```
if (pos-l == k-1) 
    return arr[(int)pos];
```

The return uses the wrong index. Try `pos-l+1` instead of `pos` (and cast it to `int`). This returns the kth item, which was just sorted to its correct place in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in a location to run it, but it seems like a lot could be wrong at this point.

In Java, when you're passing an array into a function only a copy of the array is passed, so any swaps you would do would not change the array outside of that method. Also looks like your partitions are off. Instead of passing in the partition you're just passing in the left and right bounds, and it looks like your partition method only ever sends things to the left of the partition.

This code should be commented a lot more so we can tell what you're trying to do at each point. ALso it looks like since you're swapping things into a sorted order it would be O(nlogn) since you can't sort in linear time. And why can't you use k == 0 for the kth smallest helper?

Comment: "In Java, when you're passing an array into a function only a copy of the array is passed," Not true. Arrays are reference types, like all the other classes.